# receiving lists using config parser

Tags: python, configparser

I am quite new to using config parser and have just discovered that my INI file hasn't been used as expected. as you can see below it has been seeing every letter as an individual list but I want the list to be separated by the commas.

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('Airline Gates/JST.ini')
print(len(config['Airports']['YMML']))

Output > 79
```

.ini

```
[Airport]
YMML=[E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,G41,G42,G43,G44,G45,G46,G47,G50,G51,G52]
```

I am very sorry for a poor explanation I am awful at explaining things but I will be happy to give you any more information. thanks!

Comment: I don't think you're reading your own output correctly. You ask Python for the length of `config['Airports']['YMML']` - the result `79` in this case indicates that the value is a string with 79 characters. The string value hasn't been split at all, let alone into individual characters in a list. To split it, remove the outer brackets and then use `.split(',')`.

Comment: `config['Airport']['YMML'].strip('[]').split(',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBwfq6UMxkY for better understanding of ConfigParser. For your current problem you can format the string value from ini file as per your need.

```
print(config['Airport']['YMML'].split(','))
```

Comment: your code provides invalid output `['[E11', 'E12', 'E13', 'E14', 'E15', 'E16', 'E17', 'E18', 'E19', 'E20', 'G41', 'G42', 'G43', 'G44', 'G45', 'G46', 'G47', 'G50', 'G51', 'G52]']`

Comment: I didn't add strip purposely, because I am using Python3 and in my code length is coming as 81 but for Charlie it is coming as 79, so obviously his version and code is not reading square brackets '[]'. Hope this helps.